# Configuring InnoDB for MySQL database on Mac

Tags: mysql, innodb

I'm configuring a Mac 10.6 server and I'm having trouble configuring MySQL to support InnoDB.

MySQL starts and works without a problem with my original my.cnf file. Here it is:

```
[mysqld]
#Don't resolve hostnames. All hostnames are IP's or 'localhost'.
skip-name-resolve
#Don't give threads different priorities.
skip-thread-priority
```

However, when I add this to support InnoDB, MySQL will not start.

```
[mysqld]
#Don't resolve hostnames. All hostnames are IP's or 'localhost'.
skip-name-resolve
#Don't give threads different priorities.
skip-thread-priority
# Uncomment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
innodb_data_home_dir=/var/mysql/
innodb_data_file_path=ibdata1:2000M;ibdata2:10M:autoextend
innodb_log_group_home_dir=/var/mysql/
innodb_log_arch_dir=/var/mysql/ 
# You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 % 
# of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
innodb_buffer_pool_size=384M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=20M
# Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
innodb_log_file_size=100M
innodb_log_buffer_size=8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout=50
```

I confirmed that /var/mysql/ exists and has correct permissions. I'm not sure how to troubleshoot mysql to learn what is causing the problem.

MySQL is located at /usr/local/ :
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    24 Aug 26 12:17 mysql -> mysql-5.5.15-osx10.6-x86
drwxr-xr-x  16 root  wheel   544 Jul 13 16:26 mysql-5.5.15-osx10.6-x86

Thank you very much for your help.

Mike

=========

Here are several lines from the end of the log file:

```
111027 14:41:07 [Note] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.15'  socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
111027 21:48:57 [Note] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: Normal shutdown

111027 21:48:57 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
111027 21:48:57  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
111027 21:48:57  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1595675
111027 21:48:57 [Note] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

111027 21:49:47 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql/data
111027 21:49:47 [Warning] The --skip-thread-priority startup option is deprecated and will be removed in MySQL 7.0. This option has no effect as the implied behavior is already the default.
111027 21:49:47 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/mysql/data/ is case insensitive
111027 21:49:47 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
111027 21:49:47 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
111027 21:49:47 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
111027 21:49:47 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
111027 21:49:47 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
111027 21:49:47 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
111027 21:49:47 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
111027 21:49:47  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
111027 21:49:48 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 1595675
111027 21:49:48 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@myservername.local' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
111027 21:49:48 [Warning] 'user' entry '@myservername.local' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
111027 21:49:48 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@myservername.local' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
111027 21:49:48 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
111027 21:49:48 [Note] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.15'  socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
111027 21:53:04 [Note] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: Normal shutdown

111027 21:53:04 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
111027 21:53:04  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
111027 21:53:04  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1595675
111027 21:53:04 [Note] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

I'm not sure how to read this. Can you assist?

Mike

Comment: I added output from the mysql logfile to my original questions.

Answer (score 0):

What is in your mysql error log file? That usually will tell you why mysql won't start. If you don't know where your log file is, in mysql run this command:

```
show variables like "%log_error%";
```

The you can tail that file to see what the error was. Of course, you will need to turn Innodb support off so you can start mysql to run the above command. Then you can shutdown mysql, enable Innodb and try starting it again. Then look at the log file.